# Optimize python code for working with object names

Tags: python

I have a pygtk Table with 16 squares, each of them containing a label. Label names are: label1, label2, label3, ..., label16.

I also have a timer that fires every *n* seconds. When the timer is fired one of the squares is highlighted (just set the font size of it to 18 and the font size of the rest to 12).

If there would be only 3 labels, the code would be something like this:

```
def update_grid(self):
    if self.timer_id is not None:
        self.__actual_choice = (self.__actual_choice % 16)+1
        if self.__actual_choice == 1:
            self.label1.modify_font(self.__font_big)
            self.label2.modify_font(self.__font_small)
            self.label3.modify_font(self.__font_small)
        elif self.__actual_choice == 2:
            self.label1.modify_font(self.__font_small)
            self.label2.modify_font(self.__font_big)
            self.label3.modify_font(self.__font_small)
        elif self.__actual_choice == 3:
            self.label1.modify_font(self.__font_small)
            self.label2.modify_font(self.__font_small)
            self.label3.modify_font(self.__font_big)
```

But having 16 labels, the code would be huge. I wonder if there is a way in python of doing something like:

```
            self.(label+"i").modify_font(self.__font_small)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* use the built-in function, [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) as others have suggested:

```
label = getattr(self, 'label%d' % i)
label.modify_font(self.__font_small)
```

But in reality, you'd be better off storing your 16 `label`s in a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Lots of variables with numbers at the end is a terrible [code smell](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html).

```
for index, label in enumerate(self.labels):
    if index == self.__actual_choice:
        label.modify_font(self.__font_big)
    else:
        label.modify_font(self.__font_small)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the `getattr` function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
self.__actual_choice = (self.__actual_choice % 16)+1
for i in range(1, 17):
    if i == self.__actual_choice:
        getattr(self, 'label' + str(i)).modify_font(self.__font_big)
    else:
        getattr(self, 'label' + str(i)).modify_font(self.__font_small)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world would you write that as a bunch of `if` statements?

```
modify_fonts = [getattr(self, "label%s" % i).modify_font for i in xrange(1, 17)]
```

You now have a list of the methods you can call for each label. That is, `modify_fonts[0]` is `self.label1.modify_font` and so on. Then you call them in a loop.

```
actual_choice = (self.__actual_choice % 16)   # no +1, we're zero-based
for index, modify_font in enumerate(modify_fonts):
    modify_font(self.__font_big if index == actual_choice else self.__font_small)
```